# Groupby and smallest on more than one index

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a data frame as follows

```
REG LOC DATE        SUM
1   A1  19-07-20     10 
1   B1  19-07-20     25 
1   C1  19-07-20     20 
2   A2  19-07-20     25 
2   B2  19-07-20     30 
2   C3  19-07-20     45 
1   A1  20-07-20     15 
1   B1  20-07-20     20 
1   C1  20-07-20     30 
2   A2  20-07-20     10 
2   B2  20-07-20     15 
2   C3  20-07-20     30 
1   A1  21-07-20     25 
1   B1  21-07-20     35 
1   C1  21-07-20     45 
2   A2  21-07-20     20 
2   B2  21-07-20     30 
2   C3  21-07-20     40
```

I want to find LOC with smallest 2 value of SUM for each region and date combination. For example for Date 19-7-20 and region 1, smallest is Loc A1 and C1 and for region 2 is A2 and B2. I am able to do it for one level with following code but not able to introduce another level in the code.

```
groupby(level=0,group_keys=False).apply(lambda x: x.nsmallest())
```

How can I do it for 2 levels not just one level up when I want n smallest values for a combination.

Thanks

Comment: `df.loc[df.groupby(['REG','DATE'])['SUM'].idxmin(), 'LOC']`

Comment: Use `df = df.sort_values(['REG','SUM']).groupby(['REG','DATE']).head(2)`

Comment: What if I need more than one smallest value i.e 5 smallest values. That's the reason I used n smallest.

Comment: @jezrael Thanks. It worked. I was trying another approach mentioned in the suggested thread and was not able to get smallest n values with transform. Thanks again.